# Where and how can you get inspiration ideas to render?

Tags: rendering

I am trying to get inspiration to model and then texture and then finally render, but I do not know where. I want a place where I can see unique ideas for blender which I can then develop into my own idea by editing. But I don't know where to start. How do you get along making your own idea that is unique and looks nice. I do not mind if you give a link of a site with refernece images or text ideas. But as a begginer I am finding it dificult to get ideas from reference images that mach my blender capabilities as I have only been using blender for a month.

Comment: Your question is not seems to be clear to me, what is your target, what do you want to do ? Please edit your question to more specific

Comment: Open ended themes like this are not well suited for this site, as they result in a collection of opinions or create a discussion that is beyond the scope of the site. A forum format like https://blenderartists.org/forum/ would be better. To understand how this site works please take ther [tour] and read trough the [help] section, and [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) in particular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming up with something unique is never easy—and by definition, it can't be found in a list of resources. But for just learning, you don't need unique. Look around you, maybe try something on your desk—like your computer, for example. (Or your keyboard or monitor if you've got a desktop.)